# View filter based on user input, No Code

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list

I need to take user's input for a field in a view and then filter the view based on the user's response. I have used Choice Filter Web Part and I am able to filter the view but I want to lookup the options for filter from another list. How this can be achieved? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You may have looked at this already but maybe 'SharePoint List Filter' can help you. With this filter you can lookup values from a list.